# Code doesn't get in sendAsynchronousRequest method at the first time of it

Tags: objective-c

When I push the button it calls `function1`. In the `function1`  `sendAsynchronousRequest` works only if I push the button more than once. Otherwise at the first time that it called, the code inside of it doesn't get called.

How can I make it work and what is the reason of it? Thank you.

```
-(BOOL)function1{
    ....
    theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IsAuthenticatedNA" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (data){
           result=TRUE;

        }
        else if (error)
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
            result=FALSE;
    }];

    return result;
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    BOOL m=[self function1];
     if(m){
       //do something 
     }else{
       //do something
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what your saying but if you try to step in to the code it won't work since it's asynchronous. Just put a breakpoint inside the block and it will break when the code gets executed.

Comment: When I push the button. This method works. But At the second time that I push the button the inside code works.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't get it.. What button are you talking about? What is the result you are returning on the last line of the code? Are you sending two requests and only getting one response back?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question for you.

Comment: What is 'result' that you are returning from function1? You can not use anything in the completionHandler to set 'result' value since it will return before the block is executed.

Comment: It is initialized as FALSE. And it returns FALSE.

Comment: No it should return TRUE, it can't get it in the if (data) part. But the thing that I don't understand, why after first calling this function it works. Everything initilized before sendAsynchronousRequest.

Comment: First of BOOL's have value YES/NO not true/false. Second, what you are doing above will never work since the function will return before the completionHandler block is executed. It might be possible for you to get at YES value sec on time if result variable is a member variable or declared as static (if its declared in the method).

Comment: I changed them to YES/NO.  I didn't get the part that you said " It might be possible...". Can you explain it more?

Comment: The variable 'result' will not be set before the method returns, since it is set in the completionHandler. Look at the answer below it is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(void)function1{
    ....
    theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IsAuthenticatedNA" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (data){
           //get the value of result as BOOL
           if(/* BOOL is YES */){
               //do something 
           }else{
               //do something
           }
        }
        else if (error)
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    [self function1];
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Ok I am looking about something for the queue too then.

Comment: Do you at least get a response? Try printing it just above the if statement.